# How to change the fork that a repository is linked to

Tags: git, github

I have a repo called at `MAIN/repo.git` and I've forked it to `FORK/repo.git`.  I have both of these repos cloned onto my computer for different purposes.

Using Github for Windows, a bug seems to have switched `FORK/repo.git` over to `MAIN/repo.git`, as when I do `git remote show origin`, the Fetch URL and Push URL are set to the main repo.  How can I switch this back so the corresponding folder on my local machine points to `FORK/repo.git`, instead of `MAIN/repo.git`?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

2023: [`gh repo fork`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork) allows since [gh v2.37.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.37.0) to set default repo when forking repo.

Now, If the repository is a fork, its parent repository will be set as the default remote repository. See [issue 6827](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/6827) and [PR 7768](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/7768), plus [`gh repo set-default`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_set-default).

---

2012: The easiest way would be using command-line [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote), from within your local clone of `FORK`:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/FORK.git
```

Or, in one command, as illustrated in this [GitHub article](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/FORK.git
```

---

A better practice is to:

- keep a remote referencing the original repo
- make your work in new branches (which will have upstream branches tracking your fork)

So:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git branch -avv # existing branches like master are linked to upstream/xxx

git remote add origin https://github.com/user/FORK.git
git checkout -b newFeatureBranch
```

Whenever you need to update your fork based on the recent evolution of the original repo:

```
git checkout master
git pull # it pulls from upstream!
git checkout newFeatureBranch
git rebase master # safe if you are alone working on that branch
git push --force # ditto. It pushes to origin, which is your fork.
```

Comment: Thanks.  Before I run this command, will it overwrite any local changes?

Comment: @zebra No, that won't overwrite anything. This is purely a local config setting change.

Comment: Thanks, I used your suggestion to use set-url here after it helped me!
https://gist.github.com/jpierson/b6c0815e9dd7078f6b8cc3cb9076ddf4

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier solution if you don't mind using the GitHub CLI:
https://cli.github.com/

It has a command name `repo fork`:
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_fork

It will allow you to fork a repo you cloned that isn't yours and switch the `origin` remote to your fork, just run `gh repo fork` and select "Yes" when it asks you if you wanna update `origin`.

There will be a new remote named `upstream` which points to the original repository before the fork, if you need that.